# Practices for implementing a Menu class in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java program where I have implemented a Menu class with static methods to manage menu options. Is this considered a good practice in Java programming? Here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static boolean quitProgram = false;

    static String[] customerMenuOptions = {"\n1. Search the catalog.",
            "2. Browse the catalog.",
            "3. Log in as Administrator.",
            "4. Exit the program"};
    static String[] employeeMenuOptions = {"\n1. Add a product.",
            "2. Search the catalog.",
            "3. Browse the catalog.",
            "4. Remove a product.",
            "5. Exit the program"};
    static String[] catalogOptions = {"1. Browse the catalog.",
            "2. Search the catalog.",
            "3. Go back to the main menu."};

    public static void menu(String[] args) {

    }

    public static void showIntroduction() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Fruit and Vegetable program.");
        System.out.print("Please enter any key to continue to the meny.");
        String employeeInput = input.nextLine();
    }

    public static void runCustomerInterface() {
        do {
            for (String listOfMenuOptions : customerMenuOptions) {
                System.out.println(listOfMenuOptions);
            }
            System.out.print("Enter one of the following numbers to continue: ");

            try {
                customerMenu();

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("\nThe input is not valid, you cannot enter a letter, please enter a number.");
                input.nextLine();
            }

        } while (!quitProgram);
    }

    public static void customerMenu() {
        int employeeInput = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (employeeInput) {
            case 1 -> Catalog.searchTheCatalog();
            case 2 -> Catalog.browseTheCatalog();
            case 3 -> logInAsAdmin();
            case 4 -> quitProgram = true;
            default -> System.out.println("\nThe input is not valid, please enter a number between 1-5. ");
        }
    }

    public static void runAdminInterface() {
        do {
            for (String listOfMenuOptions : employeeMenuOptions) {
                System.out.println(listOfMenuOptions);
            }
            System.out.print("Enter one of the following numbers to continue: ");

            try {
                employeeMenu();

            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("\nThe input is not valid, you cannot enter a letter, please enter a number.");
                input.nextLine();
            }

        } while (!quitProgram);
    }

    private static void logInAsAdmin() {
        File userNames = new File("usernames.txt");
        File passwords = new File("passwords.txt");

        System.out.println("\nWelcome to the login menu.");
        System.out.print("Please enter username: ");
        String username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        try {
            Scanner userNamesFile = new Scanner(userNames);
            Scanner userPasswordFile = new Scanner(passwords);
            while (userNamesFile.hasNext() && userPasswordFile.hasNext()) {
                String userExist = userNamesFile.nextLine();
                String passExist = userPasswordFile.nextLine();
                if (userExist.equals(username) && passExist.equals(password)) {
                    System.out.print("\nWelcome to the employee platform.");
                    runAdminInterface();
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }

    public static void printQuitProgramMessage() {
        System.out.println("\nThank you for using the Fruit and Vegetable program.");
        System.out.println("All credit goes to Kerem Incorporated.");
    }

    public static void employeeMenu() {
        int employeeInput = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (employeeInput) {
            case 1 -> Catalog.addFruitOrVegetableToCatalog();
            case 2 -> Catalog.searchTheCatalog();
            case 3 -> Catalog.browseTheCatalog();
            case 4 -> Catalog.removeProduct();
            case 5 -> quitProgram = true;
            default -> System.out.println("\nThe input is not valid, please enter a number between 1-5. ");
        }
    }
}
```

My primary concerns are:

Object-Oriented Approach: Is it a best practice to use static methods for a Menu class in Java? I've heard that Java is an object-oriented language, and I'm wondering if there's a more object-oriented way to implement the menu.

Separation of Concerns: Is this code maintaining a clean separation of concerns? Right now, my Menu class is responsible for displaying menus, handling user input, and directing control flow to different parts of the program.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on improving this code structure.

Comment: Questions like this do better on [codereview.se]. At least I would hope so, but you've already gotten two answers to this off-topic (on SO) question :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using a static menu is not wrong but if you want more controls on each of the options, Then I will suggest you to write your own menu class. here is a sample class what you can expect:

```
public class Menu {
    private String[] menuOptions;
    private Scanner input;
    private boolean quitProgram;

    public Menu(String[] menuOptions, Scanner input) {
        this.menuOptions = menuOptions;
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void runMenu() {
        do {
            for (String option : menuOptions) {
                System.out.println(option);
            }
            System.out.print("Enter an option: ");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();  // Consume the newline character
            processOption(choice);
        } while (!quitProgram);
    }

    private void processOption(int choice) {
        // Logic to handle the chosen option
    }
}
```

here are some suggestions,
your code is not well-separated. The Menu class combines the responsibilities of displaying menus, handling user input, and controlling program flow. It's generally a good practice to separate these concerns.

1. Displaying menus could be separated into a dedicated UI class.
2. Handling user input could be moved to a separate input-handling class.
3. The Menu class should primarily focus on controlling the flow of the
   program based on user input.

By separating these concerns, you make the code more modular, maintainable, and easier to extend.

Hope it helps :)